# Need to make XML generation code dynamic

Tags: c#

Code:

```
//Takes input as values separated by ///
string csvString = "row11,row12,row13///row21,row22,row23///row31,row32,row33";

// Read into an array of strings.
string[] source = csvString.Split(new string[] { "///" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

//Generate XML based on the ',' and source array.
// Note that dbTemplate here is the comma separated template field values (check below)
XElement cust = new XElement("Root",
                    from str in source
                    let fields = str.Split(',')
                    select new XElement("Client",
                        new XElement(dbTemplate[0], fields[0]),
                        new XElement(dbTemplate[1], fields[1]),
                        new XElement(dbTemplate[2], fields[2])
                        )
                );


string result=cust.ToString();
```

Logic:
I have got a table in SQL db having 2 columns: IssueType and template and written code to fetch the template based on IssueType .

```
IssueType      Template
Client    Name,Phone,Address
Claim     Name,Type,Date,HandlerName,SettledDate
Incident  Place,Cost,Name,Date
```

Above code generates XML output for 3 fixed csv values and corresponding 3 fixed IssueType->Tempalte values (ie:IssueType=Client). I want to make the code dynamic (Presently it will only work for IssueType=Client ie:having 3 template values). The no. of values in comma separated CSV will always be equal to the number of comma separated values coming from respective IssueType column from db. Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a hard time following the question, but I *think* you just want to change your select clause to:

```
select new XElement("Client",
    dbTemplate.Zip(fields, (name, value) => new XElement(name, value)))
```

Comment: @helloworld: Not really - it's still not terribly clear. But hopefully I've understood it well enough to help you - you just want elements with names and values, based on `dbTemplate` and `fields`, right? I've just noticed a typo in my answer, but in a minute it should be fine.

Comment: Error: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement.XElement(System.Xml.Linq.XName, object)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @helloworld: Well what are the types of `dbTemplate` and `fields`? You haven't shown either of them in your code. I was assuming that `dbTemplate` was a `string[]` or similar...

Comment: A very inefficient way will be to use IF LOOP to check for number of template values (no. of comma separated values) and hardcode it into XElement cust = new XElement. So for 1 template value loop only  new XElement(dbTemplate[0], fields[0]). For 2 use->  new XElement(dbTemplate[0], fields[0]),
                        new XElement(dbTemplate[1], fields[1]),.... and so on.

Comment: dbTemplate is string that holds the comma separated result from db (using executescalar) and fields is used like this -> let fields = str.Split(',')

Comment: @helloworld: No, you don't want to do that. The code I've given is the best approach IMO, but I can't help you make it work until you've answered the question in my previous comment. Hint: if you'd provided a short but complete program demonstrating the problem to start with, I could have provided a short but complete program demonstrating the answer...

Comment: @helloworld: If `dbTemplate` is a single string, then your current code shouldn't compile. Please provide a short but *complete* example in your question, which works for 3 values...

Comment: @helloworld: That's not a short but complete program, and now you're using `split` where you had `dbTemplate` before. But if you change the select clause code to `select new XElement("Client", split.Zip(fields, (name, value) => new XElement(name, value)))` it should work.

Comment: Cool. this is LINQ isnt it? Can you give me a good start reference to learn this.

Comment: @helloworld: I'd search for "linq tutorial". You were already using LINQ though...

Comment: Yes i Know. the ZIP part was new :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood well, but I think you can use something like

```
        var str = csvString.TrimStart();
        if (str.Split(new string[] { "///" }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList().Count > 0)
        {
            foreach(var token in str)
            {
                var fields = token.Split(',')
                switch (fields[0])
                {
                    case "Cust":
                    {
                        do something

                    }
                        break;
                    case "Something":
                    {
                        do something
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```